# Show that minimum distance to convex set equals maximum distance to hyperplane

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

If $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ s a nonempty closed convex set, how do we show that for every point $u \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus C$ the minimum distance from $u$ to any point in $C$ equals the maximum distance from $u$ to a hyperplane separating $u$ from $C$?

I kind of get the geometric intuition, but how do I show this rigorously?

Comment: Do you mean that the minimum distance equals to $\max_H \lbrace d_H \vert d_H = d(u,H), H \in \mathcal{H}(u,C) \rbrace $ where $\mathcal{H}(u,C)$ is the set of all possible hyperplanes supporting $u$ from $C$ ?

Comment: I think your "maximum" is also a minimum.  But an approach that does turn a convex contraint minimization problem into a maximization problem can be found at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)#Convex_problems

Comment: @AhmadBazzi yes, that's what I mean

Comment: Actually "The strong Lagrangian principle: Lagrange duality" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duality_(optimization)#The_strong_Lagrangian_principle:_Lagrange_duality

Comment: @CraigHicks could you give more details? What's our function and constraints in this case?

Comment: The function is the square norm and the constraint is that the other point must lie in $C$,

$$d(x,C) = \inf\limits_{y\in C} \frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|^2 = \inf\limits_{y}\frac{1}{2}\|x-y\|^2 + i_{C}(y)$$

Comment: @TSF so how does the distance to the hyperplane come in there? It seems like the $d(x,C)$ only refers to the distance to the convex set. Am I missing something here?

Comment: You have to take the dual problem to this problem. The supporting hyperplane will show up because the conjugate/dual of an indicator function is the support function.